# Anyway to unset multiple object fields using a map? [Java]

Tags: java, dictionary, request, setter

I have an object with some fields and they have setters. I want to iterate through a map from a request and based on the key name with value null - unset the field by doing something like

```
field1.set[key](null)
```

instead of having the request be a list and doing

```
list.forEach() {
  if (list.contains(key)) {
    object.setKeyName(null);
  }
}
```

Is this possible? It would be more dynamic vs having to add a new if statement each time a new field is added to the model. Disregard sanitization of the input.

Comment: BeanUtils.populate is close to what you want, but it uses the values of the map

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Reflection.

```
for (String fieldName : list) {
    Class parameterType; //get the type
    object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + fieldName, parameterType).invoke(object, null);
}
```

Comment: This seems what I need but null is throwing invalid number of arguments because I am guessing it needs to be > 1. Anyway around this?

Comment: What are the parameters? Does every method have the same parameters?

Comment: I found the answer. You need to set a variable to be null and pass that in to invoke as the value. Otherwise it will interpret it as no arguments instead of 1 argument of value null

Comment: So an Object array with null inside?